# Drop down list of images from model django ModelForm

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, image-rendering

I have a form where a user can update their profile. I want the user to choose from a drop down list of all the available profile pictures (a gallery of profile pictures from the `ProfilePictures` Model) which they want to be their profile picture. At the moment the form returns the string of the image URL. How can i make the actual image be in the
drop down so that a user can see all the images before choosing the one they want?

**Models.py**

```
class ProfilePicture(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.image.url}'


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(default=' Your Bio   ', max_length=200)
    pic = models.ForeignKey(ProfilePicture, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['bio','image','pic']
    # widgets = {
    #     'pic': ImageField(),
    # }
```

Image of the current dropdown list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can render choices manually.

If your `ModelForm` look like this:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['bio','pic']
```

then you can render this `pic` field in template as:

```
<form method="post" action="" >
    {% csrf_token %}>

    <select name="{{ form.pic.name }}">
        {% for q in form.pic.field.queryset %}
            <option value="{{ q.pk }}"><img src={{ q.url }}></img></option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    # ..
    # add other fields
</form>
```

Comment: I am rendering the form using crispy forms and functions in my views.py. Like '{{ p_form|crispy }}'. In my models i have a def__str__(self): function. Is there no way to return the object, rather than a string?